# PHP MongoDB findOne Memory Leak

Tags: php, mongodb, memory-leaks

I have found some old posts regarding the problem of a memory leak with the php mongodb driver. But none gave a final solution or explenation for older versions of the php mongodb driver.

My Version of the Driver is 1.4.5 (stable)
with PHP 5.3.10

**Code with Debug echos:**

```
     echo memory_get_usage()." in MB : "; 
        echo memory_get_usage()/1024/1024;
        echo "<br>";
        unset($cursor);
        $dt = new DateTime($day." 00:00:00", new DateTimeZone($this->timezone));
        $mongodate = new MongoDate($dt->getTimestamp());
       // print_r($mongodate);
        $cursor = $dc->findOne(array('keyword' => $keyword, 'date' => $mongodate));


        echo "Cursor loaded Doc (".$cursor['_id'].") : ";
        echo memory_get_usage()." in MB : "; 
        echo memory_get_usage()/1024/1024;
        echo "<br>";
```

** Echos True Memory Usage**

```
3932160 in MB : 3.75
Cursor geladen Doc (534cdee3c30fd1b8ee0bb641) : 218305980 in MB : 208.1928062439
```

**Code with Debug echos True Memory Usage:**

```
        echo memory_get_usage(true)." in MB : "; 
        echo memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024/1024;
        echo "<br>";
        unset($cursor);
        $dt = new DateTime($day." 00:00:00", new DateTimeZone($this->timezone));
        $mongodate = new MongoDate($dt->getTimestamp());
       // print_r($mongodate);
        $cursor = $dc->findOne(array('keyword' => $keyword, 'date' => $mongodate));
        /*
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($cursor);
        echo "</pre>";
        */

        echo "Cursor loaded Doc (".$cursor['_id'].") : ";
        echo memory_get_usage(true)." in MB : "; 
        echo memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024/1024;
        echo "<br>";
```

** Echos True Memory Usage**

```
3932160 in MB : 3.75
Cursor loaded Doc (534cdee3c30fd1b8ee0bb641) : 218628096 in MB : 224.5
```

So only one Documents causes an encrease by over 200 MB of memory.

```
bitrs3:PRIMARY> var doc = db.dailies.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("534cdee3c30fd1b8ee0bb641")})
bitrs3:PRIMARY> Object.bsonsize(doc)
16754823
```

The document loaded is truely not small, it has 16754823 Bytes so reaches the maximum Bson Size of 16 MB

Still I am wondering if it is normal that the findOne + cursor operation which creates an array out of the results needs so much memory.

Comment: I most certainly do not get this on php driver 1.4 while using both php 5.3 and 5.4, not sure what's happening here really. Have you checked memory usage after to form the MongoDate but before the findOne()?

Comment: @Sammaye i will check the give me a sec

Comment: 3932160 in MB : 3.75
MongoDate created : 3825472 in MB : 3.6482543945312
Cursor loaded Doc (534cdee3c30fd1b8ee0bb641) : 218307056 in MB : 208.19383239746  ==> doesn't seem to be the Mongo Date

Comment: I have done some investigating but I haven't come up with anything. You may want to post this to the google group, at the end of the day I think this is a problem that can only be solved by the actual driver mantainers

Comment: Thx for your help Sammaye, i think i will definetly post it to the google group

Comment: I found this intersting article which might explain some things on the php memory usage http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: PHP is very bad at memory usage, hence why it shouldn't run as a deamon, but despite arrays being huge they shouldn't be 224.5 MB in size and on my system getting arrays of 100's of fields with 1,000's of docs never goes above 20MB

Comment: The 16 MB Document has over 100.000 elements, mostly linking to other documents in our database

Comment: Since Derick or Hanes will probably ask; can you update to 1.5 and try again?

Comment: Sorry abut that, misclicked, anyway evne then it shouldn't use 224MB for one document, that is crazy

Comment: I will try an update to 1.5 and test again ;) Really intersting what the result will be

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if this is "the cost of doing business with PHP" or if you have found a bug in the driver by serializing the array (using serialize() or even json_encode()) and save it to a file.

Then you unserialize() (or json_decode()) the content of the file and check the memory usage.
If the memory usage is similar you see the actual overhead of PHP typing.

```
<?php
$mc = new MongoClient;
$collection = $mc->selectCollection("myDB", "myCollection");
$d = $collection->findOne(array("my" => "criteria"));
var_dump(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024);
file_put_contents("serialized.bin", serialize($d));
?>
```

Then loading it again:

```
<?php
$val = unserialize(file_get_contents("serialized.bin"));
var_dump(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024);
?>
```

**EDIT**: To preemptively clarify any misunderstanding.
A 16Mb MongoDB document does generally not need hundreds of megabytes of memory.

If you however have hundreds of thousands of elements inside that object, then individual element overhead starts to count times every element you have.